# How to wrap long line of re pattern in Ansible playbook?

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml

Writing a code for validating ipaddress, since ipaddr depends on python-netaddr, we can't guarantee target ansible server got it installed. The re is from "regular-expressions-cookbook", long but working well.

```yaml
- name: validate cluster -> topology_source_ip
  fail:
    msg: "topology_source ({{topology_source_ip}}) is not a valid IP address."
  when:
    - topology_source_ip is not regex('(?i)^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}?(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$')
    - topology_source_ip is not regex('(?i)^(?:(?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}[A-F0-9]{1,4}|(?=(?:[A-F0-9]{0,4}:){0,7}?[A-F0-9]{0,4}$)(([0-9A-F]{1,4}:){1,7}|:)((:[0-9A-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)?|(?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}:|:(:[A-F0-9]{1,4}){7})$')
```

I want to split long lines to "standard" lines (<=80 chars). I googled, but can't find a solution for wrapping a long re pattern in ansible playbook. Any idea?

In Python, it could be:

```
r=re.compile(
    r'^(?:(?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}[A-F0-9]{1,4}|(?=(?:[A-F0-9]{0,4}:){0,7}?'
    r'[A-F0-9]{0,4}$)(([0-9A-F]{1,4}:){1,7}|:)((:[0-9A-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)?'
    r'|(?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}:|:(:[A-F0-9]{1,4}){7})$'
    ,re.IGNORECASE
)
r.match("c10d:100::24")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"A solution for wrapping a long re pattern."*

A: Try to concatenate strings. For example

```
  vars:
    regex1: '{{ "(?i)^(?:(?:25[0-5]|" +
                "2[0-4][0-9]|" +
                "[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}?(?:25[0-5]|"  +
                "2[0-4][0-9]|" +
                "[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$" }}'
    regex2: '{{ "(?i)^(?:(?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}[A-F0-9]{1,4}|" +
                "(?=(?:[A-F0-9]{0,4}:){0,7}?[A-F0-9]{0,4}$)(([0-9A-F]{1,4}:){1,7}|" +
                ":)((:[0-9A-F]{1,4}){1,7}|" +
                ":)?|(?:[A-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}:|" +
                ":(:[A-F0-9]{1,4}){7})$" }}'
  tasks:
    - name: validate cluster -> topology_source_ip
      fail:
        msg: "topology_source ({{topology_source_ip}}) is not a valid IP address."
      when:
        - topology_source_ip is not regex(regex1)
        - topology_source_ip is not regex(regex2)
```

---

> Q: *"`ipaddr` depends on python-netaddr, we can't guarantee target ansible server got it installed."*

A: [ipaddr](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#ipaddr-filter) requires `python-netaddr` on controller not on the remote host. The task below gives the same result

```
  tasks:
    - name: validate cluster -> topology_source_ip
      fail:
        msg: "topology_source ({{topology_source_ip}}) is not a valid IP address."
      when: not topology_source_ip|ipaddr
```

Comment: Hey Vladimir, thanks for your reply. "concatenate" method really helps. The code looks clean. The reason I raise this question is that i can't use "ipaddr", because only script will be delivered to user, i can't guarantee controller has "python-netaddr" installed.